# rx-to-string and no-group argument

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

Test

```
(dolist (form (list '(+ "a")
                    '(+ "ab")
                    '(or "aa" "bb")
                    '(: bow "a" eow)))
  (dolist (no-group (list nil t))
    (princ (rx-to-string form no-group))
    (terpri))
  (terpri))
```

Output

```
\(?:a+\)
a+

\(?:\(?:ab\)+\)
\(?:ab\)+

\(?:\(?:aa\|bb\)\)
\(?:aa\|bb\)

\(?:\<a\>\)
\<a\>
```

Am I right in assuming that the value of NO-GROUP argument in rx-to-string makes no difference in how the returned regexp string will behave and that it is only for cosmetic reasons?

If I go through a package's code and changes NO-GROUP from nil to t or vice versa in every occurrence of rx-to-string, is it safe to assume that nothing will break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you *cannot* assume that nothing will break.

The groups are there *not* just for cosmetic reasons. These are [shy groups](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html):

> A shy group serves the first two purposes of an ordinary group
>   (controlling the nesting of other operators), but it does not get a
>   number, so you cannot refer back to its value with ‘\digit’. Shy
>   groups are particularly useful for mechanically-constructed regular
>   expressions, because they can be added automatically without altering
>   the numbering of ordinary, non-shy groups.

This means that the regexps themselves are equivalent, but their combinations are not.

Comment: None of the returned strings from rx-to-string in the example seem to contain any capturing groups

Comment: Sorry, fixed - the shy groups are used for regexp combinations.